# Code executing one time then triggering "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing an excel sheet for a video game to practice my coding because it has been two years since I last used VBA and my training was quite basic. If you don't mind looking at my code and giving me an idea of what might be going, I would greatly appreciate it.

Basically what I am attempting to do is allow the user to "build" the character by using drop-down menus on the main sheet. Then by clicking the "Save" button, the macro searches the CharacterData sheet (every 10 rows since the table is 9 rows and each table is separated by a space) for the table containing the character's name and updates (overwrites) it. The code works the first time, but then if I try to overwrite again, it will pop up the error. Could it possibly have to do with the data validation drop-down lists or the conditional formatting found in the table?

(Build) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkfza.jpg

(Blank template before overwrite) https://i.stack.imgur.com/qadPd.jpg

Sidenote: The goal is that later on the user can use the drop-down menu on the build menu to chose the character they want and click the "Load" Button to load in all the data from the CharacterData sheet.

```
Sub SaveCharacter()

For i = 0 To 13 Step 1
    If Worksheets("CharacterBuild").Cells(2, "C") = Worksheets("CharacterData").Cells((10 * i) + 1, "B") Then
        m = (10 * i) + 1
        n = m + 8
        Worksheets("CharacterBuild").Range("B2:G10").Copy Worksheets("CharacterData").Range(Cells(m, "A"), Cells(n, "F"))
        Exit For
    ElseIf i = 13 Then
        MsgBox ("Could not find save file. Must create one on CharacterData sheet.")
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: `CharacterData` may not be the `ActiveSheet`, so use `Worksheets("CharacterData").Range(Worksheets("CharacterData").Cells(m, "A"), Worksheets("CharacterData").Cells(n, "F"))` instead of just `Worksheets("CharacterData").Range(Cells(m, "A"), Cells(n, "F"))` - i.e. always qualify your `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, etc references with the sheet they are being applied to.

Comment: @YowE3K it worked! I am so impressed people around here can look at code on a project they don't know much about and solve the problem quickly. Thank you so much!

Comment: LOL - That is one of the errors we see a **LOT** of around here - wasn't hard to spot the probable issue even though your question didn't state which line was crashing.

Comment: @YowE3K I guess it's like a second language to those with more experience. Sorry about that, I'm new to Stack Overflow. I will try to have that figured out next time. I would upvote your answer, but I do not have enough rep. I'll come back and upvote it once I get enough.

Comment: Don't mind answering the question, but it does get boring sometimes - I like it when there is something really weird that taxes the brain cells :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code refers to a range using

```
Worksheets("CharacterData").Range(Cells(m, "A"), Cells(n, "F"))
```

Because you haven't specified which sheet is being referred to by your `Cells` objects, they are defaulting to `ActiveSheet.Cells` and therefore your code is equivalent to

```
Worksheets("CharacterData").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(m, "A"), ActiveSheet.Cells(n, "F"))
```

If `Worksheets("CharacterData")` is the `ActiveSheet`, then that will be fine, but as soon as some other sheet is active then you are trying to reference a range on one worksheet which is bounded by cells on a completely different worksheet.

You should change that part of your code to

```
Worksheets("CharacterData").Range(Worksheets("CharacterData").Cells(m, "A"), Worksheets("CharacterData").Cells(n, "F"))
```

---

A good habit to get into is to **always** qualify your `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows`, `Columns`, etc, references by specifying which sheet they are referring to.